# Iphone ignores width of image

Tags: iphone, image, width

I'm trying to build a portfolio website, wich works on desktop and mobile devices.
This is what i have right now: http://i305098.iris.fhict.nl/Portfolio/

The problem is on the image in the showcase section ,the image doesn't display how it should be doing. It works fine on all browsers and even in the GC emulator of iphone 5 but when I show the page on my Iphone 5 the image totally ignores any width or height given in the CSS.

Answer (score -1):

You should try using PHP constraints for the image so that it resizes itself nicely, (Are you using wordpress or ?)

That would be helpful, Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using wordpress

Comment: Don't you think there is a css solutions to it?

Comment: I fixed it by myself, turns out that you have to give a width and height in the html too, otherwise it's not scaling down.